# How to add Extra Text in the TimePicker in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, timepicker

I need to extra text into the picker as you see below.

[image]

For the hour section, I need to add Stunden (Hour(s) is ) and for the minute section I need to add Min.

I am using Xamarin/MAUI but in this case I access native code. So how can I change these texts in native?

Here is my code. I changed the Interval as you see, and now I need to add text to the sections.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control == null)
        return;

    var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
    timePicker.MinuteInterval = 5;
    
    Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
    Control.TextColor = UIColor.Black;

    if (!Control.Enabled)
        Control.TextColor = UIColor.LightGray;

    if (Control.Focused)
        Control.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(154, 23, 47);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add extra text in TimePicker, you can use the Picker control to customize the content to achieve this effect, I wrote and tested the following code, you can refer to:

Custom Picker code:

```
public class CustomPicker:UIPickerView

    {

        public string SelectedHour { get; set; }

        public string SelectedMinute { get; set; }

        List<string> hours = new List<string>() {
            "0 Sunden",
            "1 Sunden",
            "2 Sunden",
            "3 Sunden",
            "4 Sunden",
            "5 Sunden",
            "6 Sunden",
            "7 Sunden",
            "8 Sunden",
            "9 Sunden",
            "10 Sunden",
            "11 Sunden",
            "12 Sunden",
            "13 Sunden",
            "14 Sunden",
            "15 Sunden",
            "16 Sunden",
            "17 Sunden",
            "18 Sunden",
            "19 Sunden",
            "20 Sunden",
            "21 Sunden",
            "22 Sunden",
            "23 Sunden"
        };

 
        List<string> minutes = new List<string>()
        {
            "0 Min.",
            "5 Min.",
            "10 Min.",
            "15 Min.",
            "20 Min.",
            "25 Min.",
            "30 Min.",
            "35 Min.",
            "40 Min.",
            "45 Min.",
            "50 Min.",
            "55 Min."

        };

 
        public CustomPicker() {

            this.DataSource=new PickerViewDateSource(hours, minutes);
            this.Delegate=new PickerViewDelegate(hours, minutes, (SelectedHour) =>
            {
                this.SelectedHour = SelectedHour;
            },(SelectedMinute)=>{
                this.SelectedMinute = SelectedMinute;
            });
        }
    }
```

PickerViewDelegate:

```
public class PickerViewDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate

{

    public Action<string> OnSelectedHour { get; set; }

    public Action<string> OnSelectedMinute { get; set; }

    public List<string> hours { get; set; }

    public List<string> minutes { get;set; }

    public PickerViewDelegate(List<string> _hours,List<string> _minuts,Action<string> hourAction,Action<string> minuteAction) {

        hours = _hours;

        minutes = _minuts;

        OnSelectedHour = hourAction;

        OnSelectedMinute = minuteAction;

    }

    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)

    {

        if (component == 0)

        {

            return hours[(int)row];

        }

       else

        {

            return minutes[(int)row];

        }

    }



    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)

    {

        if (component == 0)

        {

            OnSelectedHour(hours[(int)row]);

        }

        else

        {

            OnSelectedMinute(minutes[(int)row]);

        }

    }

}
```

PickerViewDateSource:

```
public class PickerViewDateSource : UIPickerViewDataSource

{

    public List<string> hours { get; set; }

    public List<string> minutes { get; set; }

    public PickerViewDateSource(List<string> hours, List<string> minutes)

    {

        this.hours = hours;

        this.minutes = minutes;

    }



    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)

    {

        return 2;

    }



    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)

    {

        if (component == 0)

        {

            return (nint)this.hours.Count;

        }

        else {

            return(nint)this.minutes.Count;

        }

    }

}
```

Change your code as follows:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var picker = new CustomPicker();

            this.Control.InputView = picker;
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and sorry for late answer. I was in holiday. Well I implemented your solution and it seems it works but how can I retrieve SelectedHour and SelectedMinute in my PropertyChanged event or in page class? I can access my CustomTimePicker in the propertychanged event but from this control I cannot get the selected hour and minute.  By the way I tried with UIDatePickerMode.CounTimer but unfortunately I get an error => Value is an invalid value for Time (Parameter 'value')

Comment: You can check [Responding to item selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-items#responding-to-item-selection) in the official document, which provides the select method